# Не срабатывают css стили в медиа-запросе css файла

Tags: html, css, media-queries

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test_mobile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="block">TEST</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 412px) {
  .block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    background-color: green;
    color: gold;
  }
}
```

Comment: Если у вас test_mobile стоит перед test, то стили из test имеют более высокий приоритет

Comment: я поменял их местами. И все заработало. Отлично!